# Regex for detection company names in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to detect company names with regex by using Python.

This is my idea:

1. Company name should have between 1 and 3 words
2. First word in company name should be capitalized
3. One of words in company name can have .com or .co (Amazon.com Inc)
4. Last word of company name (fourth word) should be Inc. , Ltd, GmbH, AG, GmbH, Group, Holding etc.
5. Between last word of name and Inc. , Ltd, GmbH, AG sometimes can be ',' or ', '

I have tried something like this but it does not work:

```
address_1 = 'I work in Amazon.com Inc.'
address_2 = 'Company named Swiss Medic Holding invested in vaccine'
address_3 = 'what do you think about Abercrombie & Fitch Co. ?'
address_4 = 'do you work in Delta Group?'
address_5 = 'I have worked in CocaCola Gmbh'

regex_company = '([A-Z][\w]+[ -]+){1,3}(Ltd|ltd|LTD|llc|LLC|Inc|inc|INC|plc|Corp|Group)'
found = re.search(regex_company, address)
```

And I want to print results of detected companies
I have used same regex logic to find street addresses and it works good, but for company names it does not.
This is the regex that I have used:

```
regex_street = "(\d{0,6})(?:\w)\s([A-Z][\w]+[ -]+){1,3}(Street|St|Road|Rd)
```

Regex logic: number + 1-3 words + street/st/road/rd

Comment: This may be too large of a scope of possibilities for regex. Would there potentially be another way of getting the company name?

Comment: `I want to` and what problem do you face ? What is "does not work" ?

Comment: Condition 3 makes it difficult as regexes are not made for "only one of". Is it OK to match patterns where every word ends in `.com`/`.co`?

Comment: @peer well answer to that is yes and no, i do not have case where i have 2 or 3 word name with only one .com, its only one word ending with .com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```py
\b[A-Z]\w+(?:\.com?)?(?:[ -]+(?:&[ -]+)?[A-Z]\w+(?:\.com?)?){0,2}[,\s]+(?i:ltd|llc|inc|plc|co(?:rp)?|group|holding|gmbh)\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/zVHzC2/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    co                       'co'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    m?                       'm' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (between 0 and 2
                           times (matching the most amount
                           possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ -]+                    any character of: ' ', '-' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      &                        '&'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [ -]+                    any character of: ' ', '-' (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [A-Z]                    any character of: 'A' to 'Z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      co                       'co'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      m?                       'm' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){0,2}                   end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [,\s]+                   any character of: ',', whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?i:                     group, but do not capture (case-
                           insensitive) (with ^ and $ matching
                           normally) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ltd                      'ltd'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    llc                      'llc'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    inc                      'inc'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    plc                      'plc'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    co                       'co'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      rp                       'rp'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    group                    'group'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    holding                  'holding'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    gmbh                     'gmbh'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##bZAxT8MwEIVn/CtOGapYtBGCrRKKqiCgAxMbTYUcx8RWbZ/luA2F8NuD07RbJ59833t379wxSLQPw6CMQx/AC0K8aMQ3PIJPymqzWnxsy@42zZdlxtHkNI/lBhbb8Wt2Kmh@haK/d/P7v828bEdSLXWoe615ryzvXXw5Rtg7mveNx73rJepa2aZvTCVpWSWEBNGGzzb4uEmarKFDvwNlYWXYD9pxCqwtz0qbkJukQOOYPYJlRtTw3qm2hTdRKw6vk29UHqJfbEaLA@NcWTFJO8kC1AhH3EOQyu6AVbgPsKqE5x5NpQTM4FkFLqHADPJJdlZctnoSOjB4GaOcgTVIdhAnYJpaIGcF6kjFiAklxHllQ@pF9qVszbROT4efwyU4pcPwDw)**:

```py
import re

regex = r"\b[A-Z]\w+(?:\.com?)?(?:[ -]+(?:&[ -]+)?[A-Z]\w+(?:\.com?)?){0,2}[,\s]+(?i:ltd|llc|inc|plc|co(?:rp)?|group|holding|gmbh)\b"

test_str = ("I work in Amazon.com Inc.\n"
    "Company named Swiss Medic Holding invested in vaccine\n"
    "what do you think about Abercrombie & Fitch Co. ?\n"
    "do you work in Delta Group?\n"
    "I have worked in CocaCola Gmbh")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

**Results**: `['Amazon.com Inc', 'Swiss Medic Holding', 'Abercrombie & Fitch Co', 'Delta Group', 'CocaCola Gmbh']`

Comment: Does not seem to work properly since it's returning non capitalized words (ie work, named, about...).

Comment: @JoanLaraGanau No, it works fine. I provided the code and the results.

Comment: It works fine now because you edited it. Good job anyway, that's a quite tricky regular expression. Edit: maybe you only added the ```r"```...

Comment: But company name must have ltd, group, plc, holding etc. at its end

Comment: @taga Exactly what my solution does. Finds them at the end.

Comment: your regex at the beginning and regex that you used in code are not the same.  Also, what does co(?:rp)? mean and this ?i: ?

Comment: It does not without '?i: '

Comment: @taga I posted explanation, `(?i:                      group, but do not capture, case insensitively:`

Comment: Thanks, it works for 4/5, what about comma value?

Comment: Thanks but I have one more question... Sometimes name of the company is Myname Incorporated and the regex find Myname Inc.
 I know that 'Inc' is in 'Incorporated' but is there a way to find exact match? I have tried to add 'Incorporated' in the regex but it always finds only 'inc'

Comment: @RyszardCzech
Can you help me with this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68291049/regex-for-phrase-that-has-special-chars

Answer (score 0):

Use https://regex101.com for testing out regex, it's great.  For your specific example, here is regex that does what you want.  I don't see the need to test for the optional .com in this example.

```
regex_company = '[A-Z]([^ ]*[ &]*){0,2}(Inc\.|Ltd|GmbH|AG|Gmbh|Group|Holding|Co\.)'

for address in [address_1, address_2, address_3, address_4, address_5]:
    found = re.search(regex_company, address)
    if found:
        print(found)

# prints:
# <regex.Match object; span=(10, 25), match='Amazon.com Inc.'>
# <regex.Match object; span=(14, 33), match='Swiss Medic Holding'>
# <regex.Match object; span=(24, 47), match='Abercrombie & Fitch Co.'>
# <regex.Match object; span=(15, 26), match='Delta Group'>
# <regex.Match object; span=(17, 30), match='CocaCola Gmbh'>
```

Comment: please check out the type if regex that I have used for street detection, can you replicate something like this for company names?