# Regex for phrase that has special chars

Tags: python, regex

I want to make regex that will find phrases between 1 and 4 words.
First letter of first word must be capital, other can be lower.
These words can contain special chars in them or between them, also it can contain 1-3 digit number.
This is my regex, but for some reason it collects only first 3 letter of each word.

Example of texts and regex:

```
Marry Larry
Marry and Larry
Marry and Larry.com
Marry & Larry.com
Marry & Larry
Mary lowercaseword Larry
M.L.S.
M.Larry
M. L. S.
M. Larry's
Marry's and Larry's
Mary Larry's

regex = "((\d{0,3})?[A-Z]('s|'|-|.|.com)?\s?(&|[a-z])?\s?){1,3}"

found = re.search(regex, text)
```

Comment: But `and` doesn't start with uppercase letter and none of the examples have 3 digits. What's the rule for `.com`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this regex : `\d{0,3}[A-Z][A-Za-z.\-&$']*( +[A-Za-z.\-&$']+){0,3}(?:\n|$)`

First, `\d{0,3}` check if the phrase begin with 0 to 3 number.

Next, `[A-Z][A-Za-z.\-&$']*` match the first word that need a capital letter first.

Next, `( +[A-Za-z.\-&$']+){0,3}` match a space and then a series of character to form a word with a maximum of 3 occurance (4 words total).

Finally, `(?:\n|$)` match a newline or the end of the string without incuding it in the result.

if you want different special character just add them inside the two [] like this : [A-Za-z"special character you want here without quotation mark"]

Note that '-' character need escape so write '\-' instead.

check on this site to confirm : [regexr.com/61f8c](http://regexr.com/61f8c)

Comment: Can you tell me how to exclude :,  ; ? and ! from this regex? I want to find phrases that can have special chars, but not  :,  ; ?

Comment: Sorry the '-' character needed escape. I have updated the answer.